# RestTemplate parsing from Response entity to an Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First I created this method to get me a `Pokemon` by Id and parse it to a POJO class using `RestTemplate`.

```
//Service Class   
public PokemonResponseTemplateVO getPokemonFromApi(Long pokemonId) {
    log.info("Find Pokemon From Api Service Call");
    PokemonResponseTemplateVO vo = new PokemonResponseTemplateVO();
    Pokemon pokemon = restTemplate.getForObject(GET_POKEMONS_BY_ID_API + pokemonId, Pokemon.class);
    vo.setPokemon(pokemon);
    return vo;
}

//Controller Class
@GetMapping("findByIdApi/{id}")
public PokemonResponseTemplateVO getPokemonFromApi(@PathVariable("id") Long pokemonId) {
    log.info("Get Pokemon From Api Controller Call");
    return pokemonService.getPokemonFromApi(pokemonId);
    
}

//POJO
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PokemonResponseTemplateVO {

private Pokemon pokemon;

}
```

So far everything works fine, but now I have to parse a list of `Pokemon`s and I can't find a way to do the same thing with a list of objects. I already have the response correct but cant merge it to my POJO. If I change to String as the line that is commented I get the response but not the way I want it using the POJO.

```
//Service Class
public ResponseEntity<PokemonUrl> findAllPokemonsApi() {
    log.info("Find All Pokemon From Api Service Call");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    //ResponseEntity<String> result = template.exchange(GET_ALL_POKEMONS_API, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    ResponseEntity<PokemonUrl> response = restTemplate.exchange(GET_ALL_POKEMONS_API, HttpMethod.GET, entity, PokemonUrl.class);

    return response;
}

//Controller
@GetMapping("findAllPokemons/")
public ResponseEntity<PokemonUrl> findAllPokemonsApi() {
    log.info("Get Pokemon From Api Controller Call");
    return pokemonService.findAllPokemonsApi();
    
}

//POJO
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AllPokemonsResponseTemplateVO {

   private PokemonUrl pokemon;
}
```

The main goal is to get all the 151 URLs that contain the description from every pokemon and save it in my DB.

Comment: Can you share the getallpokemon api sample response ?

Comment: @ArunSai the response is to long to paste here I give the link is an Online Api for the community "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"

Comment: I believe your pojo may have some field structure issue in order to sync with the response, can you add your PokemonUrl pojo code

Comment: If you want to get the response inside a PokemonUrl instance, you need to change it to reflect the structure your json response is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you need to use `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PokemonUrl>>() {}` in your `restTemplate` call so that you can get a list of `PokemonUrl` as follows:

```java
//Service Class
public ResponseEntity<List<PokemonUrl>> findAllPokemonsApi() {
    log.info("Find All Pokemon From Api Service Call");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    
    ResponseEntity<List<PokemonUrl>> response = restTemplate.exchange(GET_ALL_POKEMONS_API, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PokemonUrl>>() {});

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the share API response of getAllPokemon, the Java POJO which should resemble the structure of response and capture should be like below:

```
public class PokemonUrl{


private int count;
private String next;
private Object previous;
private List<PokemonData> results;

// setter, getters


}

public class PokemonData{

private String name;
private String url;

// setter, getters

}
```

Cannot find what is the datatype of field `previous` because it's value is `null` in the `shared response`, Hence declared the `previous` field as `Object` class to bind its value irrespective of it's datatype.